# In Matlab, how can I find the rows where two arrays are equal?

Tags: arrays, matlab

For example, I'm looking at the first column in two arrays, and I created a logical array that finds all the values greater than 5 in both arrays.

Now, how can I find all the rows where the values in the matrices are greater than 5? 
In other words, the rows where there are 1's in the two logical arrays.
For example:
coupling = row1 == row2; 
This is just giving me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
coupling = row1 == row2;
```

should *not* give a syntax error: it should give you a logical array in `coupling` unless the dimensions of `row1` and `row2` are different.

If your logical array `row1` and your logical array `row2` have the same size, then you can perform a logical AND on them by calling

```
coupling = row1 & row2;
```

which will be a logical array of the same size, having values of `1` precisely at the positions where `row1` and `row1` both have a value of `1`.

Comment: I think there aren't the same number of rows in each array. How do I go about this in that case?

Comment: @Goldname, in that case your problem is not properly specified. If the first array has 3 rows and the second one has 2 rows, how do you define "the rows for which the first to columns are equal"? Do you compare the first two rows of the first array with the second array, ignoring the third row? Do you understand my problem?